# Как WP выводит статьи в шаблон?

Tags: php, wordpress, база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Например, у меня в файле шаблона index.php есть такой код:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</a>

<div class="custom">
    <?php the_date(); ?> опубликовал <strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong> в рубрике <?php the_category(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Читать далее</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

<?php endif; ?>

Не суть важно, какой код, главное, чтобы записи из БД выводил.
Так вот, хочу я понять, как же он это делает? Например, беру функцию the_content() и пытаюсь, так сказать, сзаду наперед проследить, как это работает. Но что-то я ничего не понимаю.

Вот так вот проследил, и все

```
./post_templates
   the_content()
   get_the_content()
        ./post.php
             get_post()
             class WP_POST
       ...magic...
                 ./wp_db
           ...magic..
```

А ответа не нашел, хочу проследить в коде прям от подключения к БД до того момента вывода в index.php, т.е. как проходит весь процесс вывода постов?

Накидайте материала или вкратце весь стек вызова. Что внутри классов WP происходит?   Пожалуйста!

С WP всего 3-й день, прошу простить, если вопрос глупый!

Заранее благодарен за любой ответ!

Comment: вызывать функцию для вывода каждого элемента?? мдааа, WP это жесть

Comment: В смысле? А как еще 10 статей, например, без цикла вывести, да для каждого вызвать же придется the_content() на каждой итерации цикла!

Comment: @mountpoint, я тут недавно пытался скормить его PHP Code Sniffer, и последний, похоже, завис - провисел четыре часа в виртуалке и ничего не выдал, кроме ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл have_posts() the_post() обращяется к основному вордпресс query

```
global $wp_query
```

Посты лежат в

```
$wp_query->posts
```

Каким образом the_content() выводит разный контент, объяснять не буду, чистая механика.
Скажу только, что можно для экперимента взять обычный for, внутри которого вызывать

```
setup_postdata( WP_Post object )
```

После выполнения этой функции всякие

```
the_title(), the_content()
```

будут смотреть на то, что подсунули в setup_postdata.